# OLEDB reading Excel File Not Working on IIS asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledb

I am trying to Browse the file then Saving that file into one folder and trying to read that file using OLEDB, Everything works file on local as well as working on IIS locally. Same thing when I am released on server it is not working, getting exception as  "Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\exceptApp\Files\TemplateFile.xlsx' is denied.", IIS_USERS  user has full permission on folder. Below is my code

```
 protected void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     try
         {
            grdResult.DataSource = null;
            grdResult.DataBind();
            BtnExport.Visible = false;

            if (fuFile.HasFile)
            {
                string readConnString = "";
                var fileExtn = Path.GetExtension(fuFile.FileName).ToLower();
                var dir = Server.MapPath("~\\Files");
                if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
                }
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fuFile.FileName.Trim());

                var fileNameWithPath = Path.Combine(dir, fileName);

                if (File.Exists(fileNameWithPath))
                {
                    File.Delete(fileNameWithPath);
                }
                fuFile.PostedFile.SaveAs(fileNameWithPath);
                fuFile.FileContent.Dispose();
                //Connection String to Excel Workbook
                if (fileExtn.Trim() == ".xls")
                {
                    readConnString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";", fileNameWithPath);
                }
                else if (fileExtn.Trim() == ".xlsx")
                {
                    readConnString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";", fileNameWithPath);
                }


                using (var dbConn = new OleDbConnection(readConnString))
                {                        
                    dbConn.Open();
                    var dt = dbConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [" + dt.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "]", dbConn))
                    {                            
                        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        da.Fill(ds);
                        var resultDt = ds.Tables[0];
                        dbConn.Close();
                          if (resultDt.Rows.Count > 0)
                            {
                                BtnExport.Visible = true;
                                grdResult.DataSource = resultDt;
                                grdResult.DataBind();
                            }                         

                    }                        

                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                if (File.Exists(fileNameWithPath))
                {
                    File.Delete(fileNameWithPath);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exlog.Log("BtnSubmit_Click", ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would set up the folder as a file share and then have the program access it via the file share address (\\server\Share), even when it's running locally

Comment: Try to give full permission on folder for every one and see if error still appears ? If error disappear this means that the point in folder permission configurations, this will save some time and make the things easier to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You must give access to inetpub folder to IIS_IUSRS on your server.